# Is $\liminf_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^T \int_\Omega \nabla F(v)\nabla (T_\epsilon(u-v)) \geq 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

With $\Omega$ a bounded domain, let
$$A(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_0^T \int_\Omega \nabla F(v)\nabla (T_\epsilon(u-v))$$
where $T_\epsilon$ is the truncation at height $\epsilon$:
$$T_\epsilon(x) = \begin{cases}
-\epsilon &: x \in (-\infty, -\epsilon]\\
x & x \in (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\\
\epsilon &: x \in [\epsilon, \infty)
\end{cases},$$
$u$ and $v$ belong to $L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ and $F$ is smooth, Lipschitz, monotone and $F(0)=0$ with derivative bounded away from zero and infinity.

**Question is**: can we obtain $\liminf_{\epsilon \to 0} A(\epsilon) \geq 0$?

By the chain rule and Stampaachia theorem, we can see that pointwise the integrand does tend to zero. Unfortunately DCT doesn't apply thanks to the factor of $\epsilon^{-1}$.

Comment: Is there any relation between $u$ and $v$? Otherwise it may not hold.

Comment: @gerw Unfortunately not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following produces a counterexample.

Set $\Omega = (0,1)$, $-F(v)(x) = (u-v)(x) = x$ (and neglect the dependence on time). Then,
$$A(\epsilon) = \frac1\epsilon \int_0^\varepsilon -1 \cdot 1 \equiv -1.$$